# Pandas GroupBy Alternative for Performance?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to make speed improvements on the this GroupBy and ideas to replace it with faster code.

The goal is to create a "Normalized Name" column which is the most frequent occurrence based on the the "Location ID". Any ideas how to achieve same results in a Pandas more efficient manner?

Here is my starter dataframe:

```
    Company Name    Location ID
0   jones LLC       F55555JONE
1   jones LLC       F55555JONE
2   jones           F55555JONE
3   alpha Co        F11111ALPH
4   alpha Co        F11111ALPH
5   alpha           F11111ALPH
```

Here are two working versions with timeit:

```
df.groupby(["Location ID"])["Company Name"].agg(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]).reset_index()
13.2 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


df.groupby(["Location ID"])["Company Name"].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
# 5.22 ms ± 75.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Output

```
    Location ID Company Name
0   F11111ALPH  alpha Co
1   F55555JONE  jones LLC
```

I saw an improvement of about twice as fast removing the Counter, however I'm running this on 100k rows and thinking GroupBy needs to go?  thanks

Comment: Are you grouping on Company Name or Location ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `apply` is really slowing things down. Try this alternative, where you take the size, sort, then drop_duplicates effectively leaving you with the mode. In the case of ties, the "modal" value will be the value that appeared "first" in the DataFrame.

```
gp_cols = ['Location ID']
value_col = 'Company Name'

(df.groupby(gp_cols + [value_col], observed=True, sort=False).size() 
   .to_frame('counts').reset_index() 
   .sort_values('counts', ascending=False) 
   .drop_duplicates(subset=gp_cols)
   .drop(columns='counts'))


#  Location ID Company Name
#0  F55555JONE    jones LLC
#2  F11111ALPH     alpha Co
```

---

Some timings

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fast_mode(df):
    gp_cols = ['Location ID']
    value_col = 'Company Name'

    return(df.groupby(gp_cols + [value_col], observed=True, sort=False).size() 
              .to_frame('counts').reset_index() 
              .sort_values('counts', ascending=False) 
              .drop_duplicates(subset=gp_cols)
              .drop(columns='counts'))

def apply_value_counts(df):
    return (df.groupby(['Location ID'])['Company Name']
              .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index())

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'Location ID': np.random.randint(0, n//50+1, n),
                                  'Company Name': np.random.randint(0, n//500+1, n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: fast_mode(df),
        lambda df: apply_value_counts(df),
    ],
    labels=['Fast Mode', 'Apply Value Counts'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 24)],
    equality_check = None,  # When tied may differ, also in terms of sorted output
    xlabel='~len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: right at 6.66 ms, which is slightly slower than my best scenario in the question

Comment: @jKraut hmm I find that rather surprising. The timing is going to greatly vary depending upon the number of groups and the number of elements within each group. So if you are at some extreme, say only 10 groups with 10K rows each, the performance can be very different than if you have 10k groups with 10 rows each. Based on my timings, the `fast_mode` I've laid out should be faster for many groups with a moderate number of rows, but perhaps you're in a very different scenario

Comment: It might help a lot if you can create an example that mimics roughly the number of groups you have, the length of your dataframe and the number of rows per group. (You can create sample data with a random seed like i did in the perfplot), and then it will be easier to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

How about we try `mode`

```
df.groupby(["Location ID"],as_index=False)[["Company Name"]].agg(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
  Location ID Company Name
0  F11111ALPH      alphaCo
1  F55555JONE     jonesLLC
```

Comment: that comes in at 8.08 ms  which is slightly slower than my 2nd example post in my question

Comment: @jKrautj `df.groupby(["Company Name"])["Location ID"]`？  groupby 'Location ID' ?